# How to I add together all of the indexes in a certain row in a 2d array?

Tags: c

I have created an array to hold and calculate the parameters for a "force trajectory calculator." The array takes in the number of waypoints, distances, and headings. I then use functions to calculate the x,y directions and vectors. Additionally, I use functions to calculate the amount of fuel remaining in reserve and distance the plane can travel with the reserve fuel. Finally, I am to output all of the information for each waypoint, including waypoint #, heading, magnitude, vector distances, and fuel consumed. So far, everything is working well except the fuel calculations. It is only calculating the fuel reserves to the last waypoint in the array. I need it to sum up the fuel spent by every waypoint.  I'll include the case with the output as well as the fuel functions.
Thanks in advance

```
     case 'V': case 'v':

     for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
     {
      printf("\nThe waypoint # %d. \n", j + 1);
      printf("The heading is %-5.2lf degrees.\n", arr[1][j]);
      printf("The magnitude to this waypoint is %-5.2lf meters.\n", 
      arr[0][j]);
      printf("The plane will go %-5.2lf meters due %c.\n", 
      fabs(arr[2][j]), (int)arr[3][j]);
      printf("The plane will go %-5.2lf meters due %c.\n", 
      fabs(arr[4][j]), (int)arr[5][j]);
      printf("The plane will consume %-5.2lf liters of fuel.\n", 
      ((fabs(arr[2][j]) + fabs(arr[4][j])) / 570));
      printf("-------------------------------------------------- 
      \n");
     }
      break;

    double fuel(double arr[][20], int n)
    {
     double total = 0;
     int i, j;

     for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
       for(j=0; j < n; j++)

        total = (fabs(arr[2][j]) + fabs(arr[4][j]));
        total = total / 1000;
        total = total / .57;
        total = 10523 - total;
      }

return total;

    }

//calculate distance in km remaining until fuel zero
 double zero_fuel(double arr[][20], int n)
 {
  double empty = 0.0;
  double total = 0.0;
  int i, j;

   for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
   {
     for(j=0;j<n; j++)
        total = (fabs(arr[2][j]) + fabs(arr[4][j]));
        total = total / 1000;
        total = total / .57;
        total = 10523 - total;

        empty = total * 0.57;

    }

return empty;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding each array element, only setting total equal to the last sum. You must change the line

```
total = (fabs(arr[2][j]) + fabs(arr[4][j]));
```

to

```
total += (fabs(arr[2][j]) + fabs(arr[4][j]));
```

Comment: Thank you, thats great. Will this work for the standard output as well?

Comment: No. That will print the sum of each pair of array elements. Each iteration, printf executes on only those elements.